# How to remove the first element of an array, and add a new element to the end?

Tags: c, arrays

What i want to do is that, i want to remove the first element of an array, left shift the remaining elements, and then add a new element at the end of array.

For example, initially the array is:

```
Array[5] = {3,7,10,22,5}
```

removing the first element i.e. '3', and shifting the remaining elements to left, and then adding a new value received as input to the last index of array:

```
Array[5] = {7,10,22,5,4}
```

In this way, I want to keep on adding a new element to the end, and removing the first element periodically. The objective of this is to keep record of the sensor readings of the last hour (by taking measurement after every minute) in real time. In this way, I can find out out the average sensor value of last hour in real time.
Help me sort out this problem.

Comment: What have you tried doing? Show your code and explain where you are having problems with it?

Comment: You probably should have chosen a more appropriate data structure.

Comment: A loop (roughly `for (int  i = 0; i < size; i++) Array[i] = Array[i+1]; i++);` or `memmove`. Show your attempts.

Comment: This is basically a circular buffer. Either use the array as a FIFO (i.e. move start/end pointers around the array instead of having to copy `n-1` items on each insert), or use a linked list.

Comment: The search term you want is "ring buffer" or "circular buffer".

Comment: var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.shift();  this will shift to the left, use .push to insert an entry to the end !!!!

Answer (score 3):

The shifting operation is very costly. We have to iterate over the while array and move every element. There's a easier and more efficient solution: A (simplified) [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

```
#define size 5
int array[size];
int headIndex = 0;

int removeHeadAddTail(int tail) {
    int head = array[headIndex];
    array[headIndex] = tail;
    headIndex = (headIndex + 1) % size; 
    return head;
}
```

Comment: If there are few values, `memmove` is probably OK and maybe even faster than a circular buffer.

Comment: While a circular buffer may provide a solution, the code fragment posted only provides for the replacement of `array[headIndex] = tail;` adjusting the index and returning the value replaced. A complete solution is generally provided in the form of a recursive function that does not require the use of global variables.

Answer (score 2):

You probably should have chosen a more appropriate data structure, but if you're stuck with an array for some reason then you can use [`memmove`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove) to shift all the elements down one, e.g.

```
const size_t N = 5;

memmove(&array[0], &array[1], (N - 1) * sizeof(array[0]));
```

and then write the new value to the last element:

```
array[N - 1] = new_value;
```

Comment: Ok, but what it's a more appropriate data structure in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable that points to the index of an element in the array. Let's call this variable `minute`. Every time you do a measurement, you store the sensor value at position 'minute', like `array[minute] = sensorValue;`. Then you increase `minute` by 1. When the variable `minute` reaches 60, you reset it to 0. 
This way you don't have to shift values, but you can still calculate the average of the measurements.

Initially, you can set the values in the array to -1 (or an other value, depends on your setup), and calculate the average only from the values that are not -1.